# issue in converting the incoming data from icloud

Tags: ios, icloud

i want to read the data stored in icloud in my application,but getting exception in the following method

```
-(BOOL)loadFromContents:(id)contents ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    if (contents != nil && [contents length]>0)
    {
        NSString * pString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:contents 
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
}
```

the exception is coming while converting contents into NSString. it causes application crash.

Comment: Why it's crashing? Post a crash log, please.

Comment: That's not very much information. What is the exception message? What data are you passing to this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my mistake , i was doing a mistake while reading data from icloud ....

previously to read data i have used UIDocument class "readFromURL:url error:&error" method ,

but now i replaced this call with following method .

```
[documentclassObj openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {


}];
```

now it's working fine .....